# Mapstruct how to construct a target object from 2 or more fields of the source object?

Tags: java, mapstruct

```
class PersonDTO {
  String name;
  String street;
  String city;
}
class Person {
  String name;
  Address address;
}
class Address {
  String street;
  String city;
}

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
interface Mapper {
  Person fromPersonDTO(PersonDTO dto);
}
```

I tried to use 2 `String` to `Address` but it throws

> ambiguous property exception

.

What should I add in the mapper to map `street` and `city` of `PersonDTO` to `Address`?

**update:**

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
interface Mapper {
  @Mapping(source = "street", target = "address.street")
  @Mapping(source = "city", target = "address.city")
  Person fromPersonDTO(PersonDTO dto);
}
```

Above mapper can handle direct mapping. 
But what if I'd like to add some business logic when creating `Address` object,

for example:

```
address.street = street.replaceAll(" ", "_"); 
address.city = cityDao.findByName(city).getId();
```

Is there a way to achieve such requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
interface Mapper {

    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(source = "street", target = "address.street"),
            @Mapping(source = "city", target = "address.city")
    })
    Person fromPersonDTO(PersonDTO dto);
}
```

Property `name` should be mapped automatically as long as it has same name and nested level

**UPDATE**:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class Mapper {

    @Autowired
    private CityDAO cityDao;

    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(source = "street", target = "address.street"),
            @Mapping(source = "city", target = "address.city")
    })
    Person fromPersonDTO(PersonDTO dto);

    @AfterMapping
    void after(@MappingTarget Person person) {
        Address address = person.getAddress();
        if (address != null) {
            // additional null-checks might be required
            address.setStreet(address.getStreet().replaceAll(" ", "_")); 
            address.setCity(cityDao.findByName(address.getCity()).getId();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that in order to use autowired bean the mapper must be a class, not an interface

Comment: Thanks. Currently it’s direct mapping, I’d like also to know what to do if there is some business logic in the adresse constructor?

Comment: @LunaticJape an example is welcomed. Anyway, placing business logic in constructor is generally not a good idea